# the questions about spark dataframe operations -Category statistics

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I want to separate statistics when key1 is 1 and 2, the key2 is the number of 1,2,3, and then displayed in tabular form.

```
val df1 = sc.parallelize(List((1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2),(1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 2))).toDF("key1","key2")
df2.groupBy("key1").groupBy("key2").agg(count("key2")).show()
```

i want to count key2 where key1 is 1 or 2 respectively. And add a new col like this :

```
List((1, 1,3), (1, 1,3), (1, 1,3), (1, 2,1),(1, 3,1), (2, 1,1), (2, 2,2), (2, 2,2))
```

The new col is the num of the key2 
but that is wrong.So what should i code?
thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is in the following line

```
df2.groupBy("key1").groupBy("key2").agg(count("key2")).show()
```

instead of `df1` you have used `df2` and instead of combining both columns in one `groupBy` you have used two `groupBy` consecutively. **There should be *aggregation* following every `groupBy`**.

So the working code would be

```
df1.groupBy("key1", "key2").agg(count("key2")).show()
```

which should give you

```
+----+----+-----------+
|key1|key2|count(key2)|
+----+----+-----------+
|   2|   2|          2|
|   1|   2|          1|
|   1|   1|          3|
|   1|   3|          1|
|   2|   1|          1|
+----+----+-----------+
```

**Updated**

looking at your updated question, using `window` function should be the required solution

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
def windowFunc = Window.partitionBy("key1", "key2")
df1.withColumn("result", count("key2").over(windowFunc)).show()
```

which should give you

```
+----+----+------+
|key1|key2|result|
+----+----+------+
|   2|   2|     2|
|   2|   2|     2|
|   1|   2|     1|
|   1|   1|     3|
|   1|   1|     3|
|   1|   1|     3|
|   1|   3|     1|
|   2|   1|     1|
+----+----+------+
```